# What easter eggs were included in the 3.6 patch?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've read several comments mentioning new [easter eggs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)) that were included in the 3.6 patch.  Most, maybe all of them are focused on the new Howling Abyss map.  Could anyone provide me with a list of them all?

Comment: Through personal experience I've found the shop keep can say "Its dangerous to go alone, take this!"  Yet I have no links to anymore so I'll just leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of at least one: Poro -- [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=--W39b_VaLM#t=49s) ([Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/1dd3c1/patch_notes_36/c9p6d3k))

In addition, in the patch preview, they added interaction between shopkeeper and the champions so it's likely there is something there as well.

Comment: cool didn't know about that one