# Are there any hidden interactions between Ashe, Sejuani, and Lissandra?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have been hearing rumors of some secret interactions between Ashe, Sejuani, and Lissandra because of the new Freljord event/patch. Has there been any confirmation of the interaction between these characters, or does it even exists?

Comment: Can you point us to some of the rumors?

Comment: Anivia does extra damage on a frosted enemy (she applies that with her own skills). The extra damage used to trigger to the 'Frost' of Ashe's ultimate skill. I've heard it was removed though. I don't know about the things in the new patch. Perhaps this can be of further use: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115683/what-easter-eggs-were-included-in-the-3-6-patch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Three Sisters is an event that occurs between Ashe, Sejuani and Lissandra. There are also some different voice lines. Check out [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jUQR4aKDdg) to see the examples.
There is also some discussion going on in [this thread](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=1164171).

Answer (score -1):

I remember a few weeks ago I was playing Howling Abyss as Sejuani, and it just so happens that one of my opponents was Ashe. So I was just casually playing the game for a good while and something suddenly weird just happened well in the middle of the game. I cannot remember the full details, but Ashe and Sejuani were suddenly talking to each other or doing their battle cry towards each other. And so suddenly a task appeared saying I must slay Ashe, and I'm pretty sure Ashe received a task to slay me. Too bad I didn't succeed though, but when Ashe killed me it just said I failed the task. Well something along the line like that happened. I apologize I could not be more detailed, but it happened to me by surprise. I have no idea how it was triggered, because like I said it happened in the middle of the game play out of the blue. So I guess that's all I have to say.